# HTTPS Server with Jetty on Android

Tags: android, eclipse, ssl, https, jetty

Im trying to get a HTTPS Server running in my Android App. I've decided to do it with Jetty (Version 7.0.2). My Problem is that I can't get the Server working. The HTTP Connector works fine, but whenever I try to connect to the HTTPS Connector the Android Browser tells me:

Connection Problem:  `Couldn't establish a secure connection.`

Heres the Code I'm using:

```java
server = new Server(8080);

        SelectChannelConnector connector0 = new SelectChannelConnector();
        connector0.setPort(8080);
        connector0.setMaxIdleTime(30000);
        connector0.setRequestHeaderSize(8192);

    SslSelectChannelConnector ssl_connector = new SslSelectChannelConnector();
    ssl_connector.setPort(8443);
    SslContextFactory cf = ssl_connector.getSslContextFactory();
    cf.setKeyStore("keystore");
    cf.setKeyStorePassword("password");
    cf.setKeyManagerPassword("password");

        server.setConnectors(new Connector[]{ connector0, connector1});

        server.setHandler(new HelloHandler());

        try {
            server.start();

        server.join();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

As mentioned before the SelectChannelConnector works fine, but the  SslSelectChannelConnector doesn't. I'm using a BKS keystore created by portecle. Is there anything wrong in my Code? Or is there a problem with Android?

Thanks for your help